# Python3 itertools permutation & combination question

Tags: python-3.x, combinations, python-itertools

I want to build a combination of all 7-digit numbers possible from a set of numbers following the rules below.

1. Each digit can only hold values as shown below from python3 list variables N1-N7 as an example.

```
N1 = [0,1,2]
N2 = [0,1] 
N3 = [0,1,2] 
N4 = [0] 
N5 = [1] 
N6 = [0,1] 
N7 = [0]
```

2. Total of all the digits in any of the 7-digit numbers should be exactly 5. Valid examples of the 7-digit numbers.

```
0120110,1110110,1120100,2020100
```

Comment: Do you mean that you are trying to build a 7-digit number using N1-N7 as 'bricks'? If yes, can they be used multiple times?

Comment: They are just python3 list variables to hold the possible values for each digit.

Comment: @nonlinear - Thanks for the response. Sorry if the question is not clear. Each 7-digit number can have only one number from each of those values - N1-N7.

Comment: Does your input get bigger? (i.e. N8, N9 etc?) more numbers inside each list? maybe the sum should be added to 10? 15? because as of right now there are only **8 combinations** in total, and if these constraints aren't changing then why generate a script for it each time you run the program.

Comment: @no_hex - The input never gets bigger. But the values are not always constant for each digit and they are all dynamic from a different system. I just picked these value sets for a smaller and clearer example. What I mean is sometimes all those digits can have an accepted range of [0,1,2] in which case the combinations will be very high. Hope I'm clear now.

Comment: So answering specifically relying on your example won't satisfy your query right? because if for example, we know `N7` is always `0` we can make our program run faster.. but you said it won't necessarily stay like that am I correct?

Comment: @no_hex - Answering specifically with this example will give me an understanding of how to do it so I shall tune it later if needed. So if you have a solution for this example set I would be glad to accept that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Cartesian product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) method of the `itertools` library,
Basically it generates all possible combinations of each group.

For example,

```py
import itertools

list(itertools.product([1,2], ['a', 'b']))
```

Should return:

```
[(1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'a'), (2, 'b')]
```

---

Applying it to your constraint that we need to pick the first digit from `N1`, second digit from `N2` etc...

```py
result = [''.join(map(str, combination)) for combination in itertools.product(N1, N2, N3, N4, N5, N6, N7)]
```

This does not enforce that the sum will be equal to five, so we can add it with a simple if statement:

```py
result = [''.join(map(str, cartesian_product)) for cartesian_product in itertools.product(N1, N2, N3, N4, N5, N6, N7) if sum(cartesian_product) == 5]
```

Resulting in:

```
['0120110', '1020110', '1110110', '1120100', '2010110', '2020100', '2100110', '2110100']
```